# Does $(\cos t , \sin (\sqrt{2}t))$ traces all the points of a square.

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

The following parametric equation recently across my mind recently,
$$x = \cos (t)$$
$$y = \sin (\sqrt{2} t)$$
And graphing on my calculator shows it eventually traces out a "square". What I am wondering is if this function actually traces out all the points within this square for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, or some region of it as the corners will never be reached.

Comment: [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/tco9glo1gu) confirms, but I think that it's just the closure which would form the square.

Comment: The irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ is the reason that the iteration is not periodic. The question whether every point is reached is interesting (+1)

Comment: Ok, i actually got a set of points which can be never included, check my argument

Comment: Since the curve is smooth, the image of $\mathbb{R}$ under this curve is a measure-zero subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So the curve will miss almost every point of the square $[-1, 1]^2$. Also, this type of curve is called [*Lissajous curve*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lissajous_curve).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It only fills the square "densely", but not completely.

Just take any $x$ coordinate you want to achieve. Then calulate one of corresponding values of $t$ for which $\cos$ achieves this value (namely $\arccos(x)$)

Then for any $k$, $t+2\pi k$ will have the same $x$ coordinate while $\sqrt{2}\times(t+2\pi k) \pmod {2\pi}$ will densely fill the $[0,2\pi]$ interval due to irrationality, so the closure is indeed the unit square.

On the other hand the point $\{1,1\}$ is never reached. Indeed for that point to be attained, the value of $t$ should be $2l\pi$ for $x$ to be correct, and $\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$ for the $y$ coordinate to be correct, so you need $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{\sqrt{2}}=2l\pi$$
which can be reformulated to 
$$\frac{\pi+2k\pi}{2l\pi}=\frac{1+2k}{2l}=\sqrt{2},$$
which would contradict the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Ok, i actually got a set of points(which your argument is discussion case of) which can be never included, check my argument

Comment: Just curious, are there any points in the open square $\{(x,y):x,y\in(-1,1)\}$ that this function will never reach?

Comment: As Sengchun Lee commented: yes there are infinitely many. To compute a concrete example simply try $\{1/2,1/2\}$, where the argument to prove it is exactly as the one in my answer

Comment: Shouldn't the graph be no-where dense by Baire category theorem?

Answer (score 3):

For a fixed $x \in [-1,1]$, there are countably many $t$ that satisfy the parametric equations. Let $T$ denote such values of $t$. $y$ has period $\sqrt2\pi$.

1. Convince yourself that $T \pmod{\sqrt2\pi}$ is dense in $[0,\sqrt2\pi]$. ([1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/843763/328173), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/903142/328173), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/450493/328173))
2. Then, convince yourself that $\sin \sqrt 2T$ is dense in $[-1,1]$. (limit commutes with continuous function)
3. However, convince yourself that $\sin \sqrt 2T$ only has countably many numbers, while any particular vertical strip of the square has uncountably many numbers, so not all points are reached. (see comment)
4. Conclude that since $x$ is arbitrary, the set of points $(x,y)$ in the graph is dense in $[-1,1]^2$, but does not contain every point in $[-1,1]^2$.

Comment: I still don't understand

Comment: How can $\sin T$ have only countably many numbers?

Comment: @neonpokharkar Since $\cos t = x$, we have $t=2n\pi \pm \cos^{-1} x$, which has only countably many values.

Comment: Ok but you still don't prove the point, question is about $\sin \sqrt{2} T$

Comment: @neonpokharkar since $T$ is countable, so is $\sin \sqrt 2T$.

Comment: Ok, i actually got a set of points which can be never included, check my argument

Comment: Because it means $\sqrt{2}=kπ$ which is obviously not the case

Comment: Plz i have edited my answer, plz consider an request to remove your downvote